# View transaction is not happening in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11

In our project, we had created a baseviewcontroller with static upper and lower toolbar and other views as the subclass of baseviewcontroller and so the ui remains constant through out the app.
 It was working fine with ios 10.3.3. But with ios 11, the button actions are happening but view transactions are not happening in both upper and lower toolbar. Code is executed but the ui updates are not happening.

```
 CustomerProfile.h

     @interface Customerprofilechange : baseViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>{
}
@end

Customerrofile.m

@interface Customerprofilechange ()

@end

@implementation Customerprofilechange
-(id)init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setupView];
}


-(void)setupView
{

    self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

    [self createTable];
    [self createBottomBar];


}
#pragma mark  bottm bar
-(void)createBottomBar
{
    [self setBottomBarImage];
    [self showBottomBar];
}
-(void)homeAction:(id)sender
{
    MainMenueController *_MainMenueController = [[MainMenueController alloc]init] ;
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:_MainMenueController animated:NO];

}
(void)backButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(pushMyViewController) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

    ///[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

}
-(void)pushMyViewController{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

}
-(void)signoutAction:(id)sender
{
    //[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self showActivityIndicator];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(signOutActionActionThread:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

}
-(void)signOutActionActionThread:(id)id
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

    SignOut *_SignOut = [[[SignOut alloc]init] autorelease];
    _SignOut = [_SignOut getActivationServices];
   // _SignOut = [_SignOut retain];
    [self closeActivityIndicator];
    if(_SignOut.isStatus == 0)
    {
        NSArray *controllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];

        if (controllers && [controllers count] > 0) {
            UIViewController *loginController = [controllers objectAtIndex:0];
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:loginController animated:NO];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Did you try `dispatch_async` the UI actions to the main queue?

Comment: Tried using dispatch_async and PerformSelectoronmainthread but the same issue exists. Added the sample code used in the project. Here the back button, home button, and sign out button are common through out the code.

Comment: You are calling: `[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:]` which is calling `[self closeActivityIndicator]` and `[UINavigationController popToViewController:animated:]` on a background thread.. You can't do anything related to UI on threads that is not the main thread. Your code isn't thread safe.

Comment: Able to resolve the issue by changing the Push navigation controller animated to NO  [[self navigationController]pushViewController:_MainMenueController animated:NO];